# Overleaf stuck on compiling forever or doesn't compile properly (No errors in the file)

Tags: compilation-error

[image: Stuck on this]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0CoI.png): [image: Compile error]

This is for an existing Overleaf template so there is definitely no error. It compiled properly last week but is not doing it this week. Please help!! I tried changing the wifi network and cleared the cache but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There is definitely too little information here to be able to do anything... please post a minimal example that recreates the problem and somebody will help. Have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: you have not shown any code but if yu are using the koma script classes this may be a known issue fixed in later releases.